# how to get records with date value of THIS year and later in ms sql

Tags: sql-server

I'm trying to retrieve orders that were created this year using this condition:

```
WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

But I still get results that have `order_date` values before 2013.
The field type is of datetime format, I thought it was varchar.

When I do `2013-01-01` instead of YEAR(GETDATE()) it works accordingly.

Comment: Why not use a greather than (>) operator?

Comment: YEAR returns 2013, not a valid date. You are comparing a string with a date, forcing a conversion of ORDER_DATE to a string value using your machine's locale

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here is my two cents

```
Select * from Order1 where ORDER_DATE between DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, 0, GETDATE()), 0) and GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
WHERE YEAR(ORDER_DATE) = YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Raj

Comment: True. Was just trying to help with the logic.

Answer (score 1):

Let's say that GETDATE() returns 1/07/2013.

This...

```
WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN YEAR(GETDATE()) AND GETDATE()
```

Would look like this...

```
WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN '1905-07-07 00:00:00.000' AND '2013-07-01 00:00:00.000'
```

This is because the value 2013 returned from YEAR(GETDATE()) represents the 7th July 1905 when cast into a datetime.

Comment: i'm not really how did that happened but I just tried it and this select "select year(getdate());" returned "2013"

Comment: yes, it return the INT 2013. If you then CAST that as a DATETIME (which is what SQL Server is doing for you in your query) then you get 7/7/1905. SELECT CAST(2013 AS DATETIME)

Comment: YEAR returns an int with just the year which can't be compared with dates. T-SQL will convert it to a date to allow the comparison to go through

Answer (score 1):

I would just make the first of January for the current year - something like:

```
where order_date >= convert( datetime, 
                      convert( varchar(4), getdate() ,120 ) + '-01-01',
                      120
                    )
```

or if like Panagiotis Kanavos you prefer to use `year(getdate())`

```
where order_date >= convert( datetime, 
                      convert( varchar(4), year(getdate()) ) + '-01-01',
                      120
                    )
```

I would make that into a function if I was using in more than one place

or (sql server 2012)

```
where order_date >= DATEFROMPARTS ( year(getdate()), 1, 1 )
```

Comment: Why not get the year using YEAR(GETDATE()) ?

Comment: I could, but I would have to cast to a string to build the date

Comment: You are anyway, plus trimming the resulting date using a redundant conversion to varchar(4)

Comment: edited my answer with @PanagiotisKanavos suggestion, but to be honest I think they both work out similar

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012 you can use the [DATEFROMPARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) or [DATETIMEFROMPARTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213228.aspx) functions to create a date from its parts. Your `WHERE` can be written as:

```
where order_date >=DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1)
```

This avoids any conversions and allows the query optimizer to use any existing indexes that include ORDER_DATE.

Answer (score -1):

Try this,

```
WHERE ORDER_DATE BETWEEN YEAR(ORDER_DATE) AND YEAR(GETDATE())
```

Comment: Comparing a full date with two integers, plus indexing won't work dute to YEAR(ORDER_DATE)